# convert series of date format pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['19940213', '10000301', '19240613', '10000501']})
```

How come I cannot convert them into yyyy-mm-dd ? I've followed multiple SO post and not working.

I've tried :

```
x["d"] = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
```

and

```
x["d"] = pd.to_datetime(df["A"])
```

which output KeyError: 'A'.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

First use `x.A` or `x['A']`, but datetimes are not valid - add parameter `format` for `YYYYMMDD` format with `errors='coerce'` for missing values because not matched:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['19940213', '10000301', '19240613', '10000501']})
x["d"] = pd.to_datetime(x.A, format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
print (x)
          A          d
0  19940213 1994-02-13
1  10000301        NaT
2  19240613 1924-06-13
3  10000501        NaT
```

[Timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits):

> Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years:

> In [92]: pd.Timestamp.min
> Out[92]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
>
> In [93]: pd.Timestamp.max
> Out[93]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')

Another possible solutions is use [Periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
def conv(x):
    return pd.Period(year=x // 10000, month=x // 100 % 100,
                     day=x % 100, freq='D')
   
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['19940213', '10000301', '19240613', '10000501']})
x["d"] = x.A.astype(int).apply(conv)
print (x)
          A           d
0  19940213  1994-02-13
1  10000301  1000-03-01
2  19240613  1924-06-13
3  10000501  1000-05-01
```

Comment: why are those date from 1000 not valid, it should work for all dates after 1960?

Comment: @haneulkim - In pandas are Timestamp limitations - check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)